# How do I escape an asterisk in a fenced code block?

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan, remarkjs

I'm writing a Xaringan presentation that includes some fenced SQL code blocks. (I'm walking folks through some code we use as a team.)

Within those code blocks, I have some multi-line comments. The comments are meant to say "You can run this to inspect the data, but don't include it in the finished script." So they have /* on a separate line at the beginning, and */ on a separate line at the end.

*Unfortunately*, Xaringan is picking up that * in the final line and taking it to mean "highlight this line." Is there a way to escape that behavior? I've looked around in the docs and don't see it anywhere. I could be missing it though.

I've tried backslashes, backtics... Presentation Ninja shows an example with a double-asterisk, but that's to highlight *and* include it, not to show it while escaping the behavior. Below is the simplest example I could come up with:

````
---
title: "Escaping Asterisks"
author: "Benjamin Wolfe"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
---

```sql
--like this:
select foo.bar
from foo;

/*
--not like this:
  select bar.foo
  from bar;
*/
```
````

I end up with it looking roughly like this—

```
/*
--not like this:
  select bar.foo
  from bar;
/
```

—but the last line is highlighted.

Comment: Good question, but I don't know the answer. I guess you'll have to file a bug report to the remark.js repo like this one: https://github.com/gnab/remark/issues/430

Comment: Even if you make it work, the correct highlighting of multi-line comments still seems to be buggy anyhow https://github.com/gnab/remark/issues/324

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I had noticed that! small wins; I figured I'll go for the text first. :)

Comment: @YihuiXie thank you! I will definitely file a bug report to remark.js.

Comment: It's probably not a preferred solution but if you put a space before the "*/" then it will show (albeit still lacks the syntax formatting). Another approach I suppose to is to omit any comments within the coding block and write the comment in the slide content itself. The latter is more about slide design though. E.g. does having the comments within the coding block emphasise something relevant to your message in your talk? There may well be situations where it's important to place your comment in the coding block so this may not be desirable by you.